# PHP Guzzle Pool requests with proxy per request

Tags: php, asynchronous, proxy, python-requests, guzzle

i'm trying to set Pool requests to multiple urls, my only problem is that i want to set a new proxy in each request, cant figure the right way to do it, tried with Guzzle docs without luck.

my code:

```
$proxies = file('./proxies.txt');
$proxy = trim($proxies[array_rand($proxies)]);

$this->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
$this->headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36';

$client = new Client();

$requests = function(array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $u) {
        yield new Request('POST', $u->url, $this->headers,
            json_encode([
                'text' => $u->s,
            ])
        );

    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests($data), [
    'concurrency' => 20,
    'fulfilled' => function(Response $response, $index) use ($data) {
        $data->result = json_decode((String)$response->getBody());
        $data->status = True;
        $data->index = $index;
    },
    'rejected' => function(RequestException $reason, $index) use ($data) {
        $data[$index]->index = $index;
        $data[$index]->rejected = $reason;
    }
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();

return $data;
```

The code is working perfect, the only missing part is the proxy change every request.

i tried to set

```
yield new Request('POST', $u->url, ['proxy' => $proxy], data...)
```

but that was just going without proxy at all..

any suggestions / help will be amazing..

Vlad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` doesn't take `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions` like its `GuzzleHttp\Client` takes so when yielding the `Request` and passing **'proxy'** option to it, Request has not effect.

You'll need to do something like this

```
$requests = function ($data) use ($client, $proxy, $headers) {
    foreach ($data as $u) {
        yield function() use ($client, $u, $proxy, $headers) {
            return $client->request(
                'POST',
                $u->url,
                [
                    'proxy' => $proxy,
                    'headers' => $headers
                ]
            );
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests($data));
```